# How do I create a chart similar to one shown below in R?

Tags: r, data-visualization

I'm trying to create a chart similar to the one shown below. But I'm not sure how can I make it in R. Can you please guide me on what method can I use to make a chart like this? Thank you

[image]

Comment: Maybe ggplot2::geom_bar() with position = "stack" ?

Answer (score 1):

This can be made in `ggplot2` provided you do some data prep first.

```
library(dplyr); library(ggplot2)
df %>%
  group_by(category) %>%
  mutate(share_not_A = sum(duration[status != "A"]) / sum(duration),
         share_label = scales::percent(share_not_A),
         width = duration/sum(duration),
         pos = cumsum(width) - width/2) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(category = fct_reorder(as_factor(category), share_not_A)) %>%
  
  ggplot(aes(x = pos, y = category)) +
  geom_tile(aes(width = width, fill = status), height = 0.95) +
  geom_text(data = . %>% distinct(category, share_label), 
            x = -0.01, hjust = 1, size = 3,
            aes(label = share_label)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("A" = "gray70", "B" = "#995555", 
                               "C" = "#449944", "D" = "#555599")) +
  theme_void()
```

[image]

Sample data

```
set.seed(42)
df <- data.frame(category = sample(1:10, 100, replace = TRUE),
                 duration = rpois(100, 3),
                 status = sample(LETTERS[1:4], 100, 
                                 replace = TRUE, 
                                 prob = c(10,1,1,1)))
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!